# How to get custom response from Facebook Graph API Post request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mern

I am integrating Facebook in my MERN Application.
I am calling this post request of facebook graph API :

```
{{facebook_Url}}{object-id}/comments
body : {message : "Your comment"},
headers : "access token"

where object-id is any : postId, commentId(to reply a comment)
```

I am getting this response when succesful :

```
{
    "id": "122108243294041566_338684118545896" //new comment Id
}
```

I want some more information in this response like sender information {name, picture, etc} or Page Information.

How can I do that

Respose required :

```
{
    "id": "122108243294041566_338684118545896", //new comment Id
    "from" : {
              "name" : "idrees",
              "picture: "https:// ...url"
}
```

I tried by researching facebook graph api docs but didn't get it